# Does allocating memory multiple times takes more time in one go?

Tags: c++

As we all know, a sequence container's (except lists') capacity is implementation-defined after `push_back` to a container which its `capacity` is equal to its `size`?

And most of the complier will reserve more momery rather than just allocate one more size and keep capacity equal to size.

So I think that allocate multiple times will take more time. But except checking `bad_alloc`, are there other reasons?

Comment: Please use fewer "?" in order to simplify recognising the actual question.

Comment: @Constructor  The first statement seems to be assertive in itself. Is question mark needed after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take `std::vector` as an example.  There are two main problems if you allocate only a small amount each time more memory needed:

1. Allocation is typically followed by copying the values in the container.  This can be expensive if there is a lot of data, or the value type has an expensive copy (or move) constructor.
2. Small allocations may increase heap fragmentation, and will certainly increase heap bookkeeping overhead.  Each allocation has a fixed cost in addition to the variable cost (proportional to the allocation size).

Comment: Quite interesting. But I still cannot get the first item. Why it's relative to copy/move time? I think the times call to these constructors are same.

Comment: @Constructor: For `std::vector`, *all* elements must be copied *each* time memory is allocated, because the allocation is for the entire vector.  So if you allocate in chunks of 10 elements and insert values at the end repeatedly, you will copy all 10, then 20, then 30, then 40 elements when the 41st is inserted.  The first elements are copied on every reallocation.